# Getting Custom Field Values in Liferay

Tags: java, liferay-6, expando

I added a custom field in Liferay (JournalArticle), and set the value (manuel).

```
Custom Field:  Processroles     (= Group of Text Values)      
Value: Dummy,Sourcer
```

How can I search all JournalArticles with this Custom Field Values?
If I try this, I get only the articles for one Value:

```
String customNameAttribute = "Dummy";
List<ExpandoValue>value = ExpandoValueLocalServiceUtil.getColumnValues(companyId,   classNameId, ExpandoTableConstants.DEFAULT_TABLE_NAME, customAttributeName, -1, -1);
```

But I need the articles with the Value "`Dummy,Sourcer`", or only "`Dummy`" or only "`Sourcer`" (like substrings).

Answer (score 0):

There is [a thread](http://www.liferay.com/community/forums/-/message_boards/message/6027190) on the Liferay forum where Ray Augé explains what needs to be done.
The solution requires coding against the lucene index or against the database directly. Out
of the box liferay does not search in the custom fields.

Good luck!